# How to update an existing row or table of an existing xlsx file using pyexcel for python

Tags: python, excel, automation, office-automation

I am trying to use **python** to update an **xlsx spread sheet** used for keeping track of weekly trends/metrics. This particular xlsx file has 4 sheets on “Sheet one” I have 52 tables, one for each week of the year. Each table is named “table1- table52” I would like to search the sheet for the appropriate table of the current week and only update that table. I have used the below code to write to a file but it strips out all of the existing format and formulas I have set up to auto populate other sheets.  Also it does not write to the existing file its output is a brand new file.

So in a nut shell I would like to open **test1.xlsx** read **sheet one** find **table3** and update **columns** (RR, OVP, CVP, TVC, and PP) or **rows** whichever one is easier. I’m sure there is probably something simple I am missing.

I have attached a picture of the xlsx file and the python cod e I have so far. I have looked at numpy, openpyxl, pandas, and xlsxwriter. I am open to using any one of these modules

[image: test1.xlsx]

```
#How to update an existing row or table of an existing file using pyexcel for python
import pyexcel as pe
import pyexcel.ext.xls

RR1 ="Null"
OVC1 =1
CVC1 =1
TVC1 =1
PP1 =1

sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="test1.xlsx") # Original file.
sheet.row[3] = [RR1 , OVC1 , CVC1 , TVC1 , PP1] # Parameters I wish to use to update original file.
sheet.save_as("test.xlsx") # This is a different file
print pe.get_sheet(file_name="test.xlsx")
```

Comment: does my question need more explanation or details? If so I am more than happy to explain.

Comment: If this is just not possible any input would be greatly appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

[openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) does a great job opening an existing Excel (xls/xlsx) and updating a specific row, col.

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet['A1'] = 'hello world'
xfile.save('text2.xlsx')
```

We can also use row, column notation like

```
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'hello world'
```